# Unbelievable! chef-client always stick to an old version of dependence cookbook regardless of a newer one on chef server

Tags: chef-infra, version, cookbook

The problem is like this:

I have two common cookbook, named `common1`, `common2`, they have multiple versions.

```
$ knife cookbook show common1
common1   1.0.1  1.0.0
$ knife cookbook show common2
common2   1.0.1  1.0.0
```

Cookbook `test1` depends on the `common1`:

cookbooks/test1/metadata.rb

```
...
depends 'common1'
```

without explicit version specification such as `depends 'common1' = '1.0.1'`.

Cookbook `test2` are similar, but it depends on both `common1`, `common2`.
cookbooks/test2/metadata.rb

```
...
depends 'common2'
depends 'common1'
```

Now the wired thing is that:
all cookbooks are always using old `common1`, while newer `common2` are being used as expected.

```
# chef-client -o test1 --why-run | egrep -- '- common'
  - common1 (1.0.0)
# chef-client -o test2 --why-run | egrep -- '- common'
  - common2 (1.0.1)
  - common1 (1.0.0)
```

I dumped the http data between chef client and server, the only difference is that
the chef client node was bootstrapped with an old test1 as its runlist, which used old `common`, the `knife node` command shows that. the `common2` is not in runlist.

I suspect the bootstrap timing cookbook version matters, interfere new version.

Can anyone explain this issue?

Other info:

- Chef-client version: 4.14.29
- Host: Ubuntu Bionic

EDIT: more info, the  ... in the test1/metadata.rb matters

```
...
depends 'common1'
```

it is

```
depends 'base'
depends 'common1'
```

where the `base` cookbook has multiple versions.
once I removed the `depends 'base'`, it works as expected, the newer common1 get used.

Still checking. So far I have not found the `base` cookbook declared specific version of anything, the latest `base` cookbook has no any dependence, but still caused the issue.

Comment: Cookbook versions can also be "pinned" in Chef environments. Which environments do these nodes belong to? Does that environment specify cookbook versions?

Comment: yeah, I have also checked the environment, there is a `"cookbook_versions": {}` declaration. Also checked role, no version specific info.

Comment: More info come up, see the EDIT.